# Sending object to firebase using dynamic key value

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have a table component that I am using to display the information from all other components in my app. This means that when I send data I can't use the following:

```
db.collection(collectionName).add({
  key1: val1,
  key2: val2,
  etc...
})
```

Because the keys could be different depending on which component is using table. I've thought about doing this with a .map() or forEach going through each key but I keep getting syntax errors.

I originally assumed that I could just send the object new_row but that doesn't seem to work properly.

Here is my table component:

```
class Table extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        rows: null,
        temprows: null,
        newrow: null,
        parent: this.props.tableComponent
    }
}
    addRow = function(){
      var new_rows = [...this.state.rows];
      new_rows.push(this.state.newrow);
      var new_row = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new_rows[0]));

      Object.keys(new_row).forEach(function(index) {
        new_row[index] = '';
      });

      db.collection(collectionNAame).add({
         I want to add the data here
      })

      this.setState({
        rows: new_rows,
        newrow: new_row
      });
}
```

Is there also a better approach, some other method aside from .add for this specific case?

Comment: what are you passing to .add?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. I originally thought I could just put new_row in .add() but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In db.collection `.add` method, spread and pass `this.state.newrow` and in the `then` block update your state. Also in your `addRow` function, the `new_row` should be obtained from state (not `new_rows[0]`

**Like this**

```js
class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rows: null,
      temprows: null,
      newrow: {},
      parent: this.props.tableComponent
    };
  }
  addRow = function() {
    var new_rows = [...this.state.rows];
    new_rows.push(this.state.newrow);
    //   var new_row = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new_rows[0]));
    var new_row = { ...this.state.newrow };

    db.collection(collectionNAame)
      .add({
        ...this.state.new_row
      })
      .then(() => {
        Object.keys(new_row).forEach(function(index) {
          new_row[index] = "";
        });
        this.setState({
          rows: new_rows,
          newrow: new_row
        });
      });
  };
}
```